# Programmatically access the data from the Parallel Kernel Status window

Tags: parallelization, kernel, timing

I want to show the parallel kernel status within a notebook, and not in the separate Parallel Kernel Status window.

How can I programmatically access the Performance Measurements data shown in the Status window?

[image]

Comment: I edited your post to make it easier to understand.  Please review my edits.

Comment: Are you simply looking for ``Parallel`Developer`KernelStatus[]`` (try it) or do you want to get the actual numbers?

Comment: Wow!! The problem is solved easily this way !! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the status inline within a notebook (and not a separate window), first trigger loading the parallel tools:

```
Parallelize;
```

The evaluate

```
Parallel`Developer`KernelStatus[]
```

If you need to know how each column in this table is computed, take a look at

```
<<GeneralUtilities`

PrintDefinitions["Parallel`Status`Private`remoteStatus"]
```

It is in fact [`TimeUsed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeUsed.html) that's being reported.

Spelunking reference:

- `` NotebookOpen@FindFile["Parallel`Status`"] ``