# Difference between Timing, AbsoluteTiming, and Elapsed?

Tags: date-and-time, timing, function-comparison

In the picture below,
Difference between `Timing`, `AbsoluteTiming`, `Time` and `Elapsed`?
I want to know the meaning of each.

[image]

And in this case, how is my CPU distributed and utilized? 
I am curious about the principle. 
For reference, my PC is Quadcore 2.7 and the RAM is 16M.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133567/12 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/difference-between-absolutetiming-and-timing